# How to move bottom textFields up when key board appears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

fields in my view, i want to move my text-view up when keyboard appears when i started entering text in 6th, 7th, 8th. text-Fields only.

Comment: just google it before posting the question at least

Comment: can u please send me a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried solution for you question and I simply got.

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 80.0
@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSInteger tagTF;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)setMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUP
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
  CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
  if(movedUP)
  {
    rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
  }
  else{
    rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
  }
  self.view.frame = rect;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate Methods

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  tagTF = textField.tag;
  if(textField.tag>=6)
  {
    if(self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setMovedUp:YES];
    }
  }
  return YES;
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if(textField.tag>=6)
   {
     [self setMovedUp:NO];
   }
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
 }
```

From my above answer I set the textField tag from 1 to 8.It works perfectly what you want.Please set the delegate for textField.

Answer (score 0):

I have an extensive blog post explaining how to do this:

[**Shifting views to make room for the keyboard**](http://wareto.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/shifting-views-for-the-keyboard.html)

The gist of it is that you add notification handlers for the keyboard will show and keyboard will hide notifications. In those handlers, you get the height of the keyboard, then do some math to figure out how much you need to move the field up so the keyboard doesn't cover it. You then move your view controller's view up just enough to keep the field exposed.

It gets more complicated than that, but that's all covered in the blog post (which is part of [**a larger blog post on animating random shapes**](http://wareto.com/animating-shapes-using-cashapelayer-and-cabasicanimation) that includes a working example of the keyboard technique.)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options for that.

I was using TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView for a long time. Right now, i am using IQKeyboardManager much more simple and easy to integrate.

[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/)

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7) is the official documentation by Apple regarding handling the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
Float y = frame.origin.y - 70;
frame.origin.y = y;
self.view.frame = frame;
return YES;
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
Float y = frame.origin.y + 70;
frame.origin.y = y;
self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

if you have change y value(like 70, 80, ...)in textFieldShouldBeginEditing method, and add same value to y in textFieldDidEndEditing method.

try this code.